# In the par graphics module of R, assign a vector as the "srt=" argument?

Tags: r, string, plot, rotation, par

If you are making a plot, and you make x-axis labels using text(), then you can specify a string rotation or `srt` argument and a number to rotate the axis label. For instance, `srt=45` rotates the text to 45 degrees.

Say I have exactly 31 columns. If I wanted the first to be horizontal, and then for them to become progressively more slanted, with the last being vertical, one could conceivably write:

```
slant=seq(0, -90, -3)
plot(some stuff)
text(x=mid, y=y.min-20, labels=chrs, xpd=TRUE, srt=slant, adj = 1, cex=1)
```

where the length of mid, chrs, and slant are the same.

Is there some way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
plot.new()
Map(text, letters[1:5], x=seq(0,1,length=5), y=0.5, srt=seq(0,90, length=5))
```

Comment: And you could wrap an `invisible(...)` around it all if you don't want all the `NULL`'s printing out.

Comment: @thelatemail good point. i tend to assign to a dummy variable instead, or use `plyr::m_ply`

Answer (score 1):

I spent a bit more time on this. I devised a different solution:

```
    for(i in 1:31){
    text(x=mid[i], y=y.min-(17+i), labels=chrs[i], xpd=TRUE, srt=labelrotationparam[i], adj = 1, cex=1)
    }
```

Note that I also incremented the y value with i as well which keeps the labels uniformly below the axis.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you could make this happen with a simple `for` loop:

```
slant=seq(0, -90, -3)
plot(1:31,1:31, type="n")

for(i in 1:length(slant)) {
  text(x=1+i, y=1, xpd=TRUE, srt=slant[i], labels=letters[i], adj = 1, cex=1)
}
```